# Display bug when zoom out in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have problem with zooming on my webpage. I have bind on mouse wheel, to do dynamic zooming with mouse. Main element with background is about 4000px. Here is screenshot, how it looks like:
[image: http://prntscr.com/3p7w3d]

When I want to zoom out, to see a whole element, everything is messed (context menu dissapear, background-image is lost...). Here is screenshot on zoom out:
[image: http://prntscr.com/3p7w6c]

Thats is CSS on actual element:

```
element.style {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(3145px, 1463.6364px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scaleX(5) scaleY(5) scaleZ(1);
  width: 1437.5561545372866px;
  height: 800px;
  cursor: inherit;
}
.bg-slide {
  background-color: transparent!important;
  background-image: none!important;
  z-index: -2;
  border: 0!important;
}
```

It must be chrome issue, but I don't know where, because it works well in firefox, screenshot from ff:
[image: http://prntscr.com/3p7wpa]

Comment: any output to the console?

Comment: nothing, console is totaly empty

Comment: are you designed this for big screen?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I think you missed not prefixed stuff: transform-style & transform... or should take ou the prefixed ones?

Comment: prefix `-webkit` is necessary, if you mean that

Comment: Stupid question, but do you really need the `translate3d`? Isn't `scale` enough?

Comment: Yes, because user can resize it, drag it and also rotate it.

Comment: Did anybody solve this problem meanwhile??

Comment: @SchweizerSchoggi my colleague solved it, but it is more than 1 year old and we did a lot of edits to the site. Yes it works good in our project, but I don't remember what did he changed.